# tkenv gui works, then doesn't under windows 7

Tags: windows, tk-toolkit, omnet++

OMNet++ v4.6.  Windows 7 Professional.

I have been using the supplied `omnetpp.cmd` from `\omnetpp-4.6\bin` for over a month with success, after a few failures (null pointers in OMNet) the OMNeT Eclipse editor will start, but when running a simulation the `Tkenv` window will no longer appear.
I get the taskbar icon, but no window.

When I run OMNet++ using `mingwenv.cmd` which gives the bash shell, omnetpp works as expected.

I have rebuilt the OMNet++ 4.6 environment from the `.zip` file again with no improvement.

I deleted the `.tklenvrc` file for my simulation (as suggested in the *"OMNET++ Tkenv/GUI doesn't appear anymore"* question) but this has no effect.  One could say, "Just use the bash shell" but I'd like to keep at a Windows level.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is this affecting just your simulation or all simulations (for example, the TicToc tutorial)?

Comment: This is affecting all simulations, even the TicToc tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that the recommended way of running OMNeT++ simulations is to run them from `mingwenv`.

If you really have to run them from command prompt you must ensure that your path contains:

```
omnetpp_root/bin;omnetpp_root/tools/win32/usr/bin;omnetpp_root/tools/win32/mingw32/bin
```

Also be aware that `<omnetpp_root>/bin/omnetpp.cmd` is used to start the IDE while the simulations should be started from the `mingwenv.cmd` bash prompt. These two things are totally unrelated (i.e. the IDE and the simulations running in Tkenv)

Comment: Rudi, AlBlue, I did add these to the system PATH, logged out, and even rebooted the system.  These settings did not have any affect on the omnetpp.cmd execution of the simulator's Tkenv GUI.  The documentation assumes operation under a Unix-like shell (i.e. mingwenv) and the product does operate in that fashion.  I just wondered why it worked, and then didn't using the .CMD file.